# Trigger in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I create the following tables:

```
create table Tasks(
code varchar2(9),
name varchar2(40),
start_date date, 
end_date date,
constraint pk_code primary key (code)
);

create table secondary_Tasks(
code varchar2(9),
code_primary varchar2(9),
name varchar2(40),
start_date date, 
end_date date,
constraint pk_code2 primary key (code),
constraint fk_code foreign key (code_primary) references Tasks (code)
);
```

I inserted the following datas:

```
insert into Tasks values ('001','Task1',to_date('2010-02-15','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2011-04-12','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into Tasks values ('002','Task2',to_date('2015-08-11','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2015-09-25','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into Tasks values ('003','Task3',to_date('2016-05-09','YYYY-MM-DD'),null);
insert into Tasks values ('004','Task4',to_date('2014-01-23','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2014-06-04','YYYY-MM-DD'));

insert into secondary_Tasks values ('s01','001','Secundary_Task1',to_date('2010-03-16','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2011-05-13','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into secondary_Tasks values ('s02','002','Secundary_Task2',to_date('2015-09-12','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2015-10-26','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into secondary_Tasks values ('s04','004','Secundary_Task4',to_date('2014-02-24','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2014-07-05','YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

The question is how to make a trigger that does not allow me to add a secondary task to task '003' because It hasnt finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to test right now, but I'd try something like

```
create or replace trigger secondary_tasks_bi
before insert or update on secondary_tasks for each row
declare
   v_dummy varchar2(1);
begin
   select null
     into v_dummy
     from tasks
    where code = :new.code_primary
      and end_date is null;

   raise_application_error(-20001, 'Can''t add a secondary task to task ' || :new.code_primary || ' because it hasn''t finished');

   exception
      when no_data_found then
         null;
end;
/
```

Note that this assumes that code_primary is never null: you probably want to add a NOT NULL clause to it.

Comment: @Python241820 One note. If you have system when several users can simultaneously modify date. For ex. between select and raise another user can change end_date to null or set date to not null and raise error would be misleading. I would recommend this approach in special cases. In particular issue this can be the solution but don't spread it in all similar cases. It can be the cause of very weird bugs.

Comment: @EvgeniyK. so I need to put "before insert OR UPDATE on secondary_tasks for each row" in the trigger.

Comment: @Python241820 No. Trigger can't save you from simultaneously work. You should think it is good for you to just ignore this error if this situation has happend. In partitcular ex. user can see this error(means someone simult. change date to not null). User see error, wonder, think for a moment and try again and task is inserted. Then in support you can say you aren't lucky, someone work with this record. When user doesn't see error and task is added(someone simult. change not null to null) then trigger it is bad. Which of this two variant are posiible in your business-logic?

Comment: Maybe this is beyond the scope of the original question, but concurrent access to data is not the only problem you might face: what if end_date is set to null and there are already records in secondary_tasks? You'd need another trigger (on tasks) to check for this condition.

Comment: True, I'll try to fix that part @archimede